# Applying same style to multiple child divs

Tags: html, css

Here is my html

```
<div id="d1">
                <div>1</div>
                <div>2</div>
                <div>3</div>
                <div>4</div>
            </div>

<div id="d2">
                <div>1</div>
                <div>2</div>
                <div>3</div>
                <div>4</div>
            </div>
```

In the CSS, I have following.

```
#id1 > div {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#id2 > div {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

I wanted to combine it in following values.

```
#id1 > div #id2 > div  {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

But this does not work. I can add a class and apply to all 8 divs but I am wondering if there is any better way of getting this done.

Comment: #id1 > div `,` #id2 > div (notice the comma)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#id1 > div, #id2 > div  {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Multiple CSS selectors should be separated by a coma.

Answer (score 1):

first, your selector is lacking a comma:

```
#id1 > div, #id2 > div  {
```

afaik, assigning a css class to the `id` divs would be best practice. an alternative might be the following selector:

```
#id1 > div, #id1 ~ div[id] > div  {
```

you chose all `div` children of `div` siblings of `#id1` sporting an `id` attribute.
it smells like some dirty hack though...

Answer (score 0):

Separate with Comma

```
#id1 > div, #id2 > div  {
border: 1px solid white;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
margin: 5px;
}
```